# Helm Go Templating using Dictionary. I am need help in getting the values

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I can not find a way to iterate over a range in helm templating. I have the next definition in my values.yaml

***Variable dictionary  to be consumed***

```
projects:
  - tenants: imc
    namespaces: 
      - name: test-1
        company: inter
        environments:
          - build 
          - dev 
          - stage
          - test
      - name: test-2
        environments:
          - build 
          - dev 
          - stage
          - test
      - name: test-3
        environments:
          - build 
          - dev 
          - stage
          - test
```

***Code snippet***

```
{{- range $key, $value := .Values.tenants }}
{{- range $nkey, $nvalue := .namespaces }}
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  annotations:
    parent_project_name: {{ $value.name }}
    company: {{ $value.company }}
    openshift.io/description: ""
    openshift.io/display-name: ""
  labels:
    tenant: {{ $value.tenants }}
  name: {{ $value.name }}-{{ $nvalue }}
spec: {}
status: {}
{{- end }}
{{- end }}
```

***I need help in consuming the variable into the template***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May you give the expected output? This is what I guess.

values.yaml

```yaml
projects:
  - tenants: imc
    namespaces: 
      - name: test-1
        company: inter
        environments:
          - build 
          - dev 
          - stage
          - test
      - name: test-2
        environments:
          - build 
          - dev 
          - stage
          - test
      - name: test-3
        environments:
          - build 
          - dev 
          - stage
          - test
```

templates/ns.yaml

```yaml
{{- range $key, $value := .Values.projects }}
{{- range $nkey, $nvalue := .namespaces }}
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  annotations:
    parent_project_name: {{ $nvalue.name }}
    company: {{ $nvalue.company }}
    openshift.io/description: ""
    openshift.io/display-name: ""
  labels:
    tenant: {{ $value.tenants }}
  name: {{ $nvalue.name }}
spec: {}
status: {}
{{- end }}
{{- end }}
```

cmd

```bash
helm template --debug test .
```

output

```yaml
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  annotations:
    parent_project_name: test-1
    company: inter
    openshift.io/description: ""
    openshift.io/display-name: ""
  labels:
    tenant: imc
  name: test-1
spec: {}
status: {}
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  annotations:
    parent_project_name: test-2
    company: 
    openshift.io/description: ""
    openshift.io/display-name: ""
  labels:
    tenant: imc
  name: test-2
spec: {}
status: {}
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  annotations:
    parent_project_name: test-3
    company: 
    openshift.io/description: ""
    openshift.io/display-name: ""
  labels:
    tenant: imc
  name: test-3
spec: {}
status: {}
```